# Sinch android group message not work

Tags: sinch

In your website mention 1-1 and group message feature but in API we didnt see that one. so can you please guide us. is there any multi media feature in chat ?

Comment: I am talking group message system and also image ,audio facility

Comment: mail sales@sinch.com to ask these questions, its not a programming question

Comment: i was already did but no reply on that . support system too much POOR

Answer (score 1):

Your question should be more specific. Where is that 1-1 and group message feature? I think there is no any muliti media feature in chat.